# Why am I getting KeyError when calling dictionary key in self.assertEqual signature?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unittest

I'm setting up a test class using unittest to test a function that takes in a JSON file and returns a dictionary. I'm using the `assterEqual` method to perform two tests. One checks that the type returned is indeed a dictionary. The second test checks that the value returned for a given key matches what I expect.
This is the function I'm testing:

```
def convertToDict(file):
    import json
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except:
        return {}
```

Prior to executing the test, I use the `SetUp()` method to create a test fixture that writes the following data to a JSON file called `test.json`:

`{"Greeting":"Hello World"}`

Then I use the following signatures to test my function:

```
def test_convertToDict(self):
    self.assertEqual(type(JSONfile.convertToDict("TestFolder/test.json")), dict)
    self.assertEqual(JSONfile.convertToDict("TestFolder/test.json")["Greeting"],"Hello World")
```

The first test passes, but the second test fails due to a key error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../TestChoreHelpers.py", line 18, in test_JSONFile
    self.assertEqual(JSONfile.convertToDict("TestFolder/test.json")["Greeting"],"Hello World")
KeyError: 'Greeting'
```

I don't understand why I am getting a `KeyError`.

Minutes after writing this question, I began to wonder if my test fixture is incomplete and therefore my `converToDict()` returns an empty dictionary, `{}`. I will continue to add more error handling to my function to debug this. I have a feeling that my `convertToDict()` function cannot locate the file I pass during the test.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?  Strip down your unit test to the bare minimum to reproduce the error.

Comment: Your suspicion is very likely correct. Let us know how it turns out :)

Comment: Cireo, I have a feeling you saw the error but wanted me to figure it out on my own. Check out the other comment I made where I explain my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in my text fixture. After I added this to my `convertToDict()` fuction

```
except FileNotFoundError:
    return "Could not locate file."
```

I discovered that my function could not locate a file that was being passed to it because the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods were implemented incorrectly. I was using `SetUp()` instead of `setUp()`, and `TearDown()` instead of `tearDown()`.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should avoid using "bare" `execpt:` clauses with `try` — i.e. because they can hide unexpected exceptions and cause confusion.